# Script throws error for folders with space in them

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have a .vbs file that opens and launches an Excel file. The issue is that it errors when it reaches a space in my folder path.

The code is:

```
Dim excel, oWB

Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set oWB = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\My Folder\Desktop\file.xlsm")
oWB.save

oWB.Application.Quit
```

I recieve the error

> There is no file extension in 'C:\Users\My '.

I've tried

```
 Set oWB = excel.Workbooks.Open(Chr(34) & "C:\Users\My Folder\Desktop\file.xlsm" & Chr(34))
```

and

```
Set oWB = excel.Workbooks.Open("""C:\Users\My Folder\Desktop\file.xlsm""")
```

as suggested from other forums.

UPDATE:

So I am convinced that the error is coming from the "Task Scheduler" and not the vb script. I tried changing the file path name in the vb script, but the error was the same even though I changed it completely. Then I realized that under "actions > start a program > add arguments (optional)" in the "Task Scheduler", I was calling the same file path to launch the vb script. I don't think the "Task Scheduler" registers space characters in folder names for some reason.

I use Task Scheduler to run the vbscript early in the morning before I come into the office so that it runs multiple excel files with automatted macros that launch.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce. Try to comment the lines `oWB.save` and `oWB.Application.Quit` and add `excel.Visible = True`. See if the file opens for you

Comment: PS This is an EXCEL error not a VBScript error.

Comment: 'Should there really be a **USER** named `My Folder` I'm in doubt.

Comment: @Noodles <begin rant>Who would have thought to tag a question in VBScript with [a tag containing a different language](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/synonymize-very-bad-amalgam-tags-excel-vba-access-vba-word-vba-powerp)?</ end rant>

Comment: @ZevSpitz They are just COM objects. Tag should Excel-Object, not Excel-vba as it VBA is irrelevant to using Excel. If calling API functions in VB then code looks very similar to C programs doing the same thing. Likewise any COM program looks similar as they call the exact same objects.

Comment: @Noodles You don't have to convince me. Upvote on that proposal if you think it's a valid solution to the problem.

Comment: I suspect that the error comes from a macro in `file.xlsm`. That's why I added the tag [tag:excel-vba].

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Digressing -- The error appears to be happening in the call to the `Open` method on the `Worksheets` collection. If the error had nothing to do with the VBA in `file.xlsm`, how would you have tagged this question -- Is [tag:excel] too broad? Is [tag:excel-vba] not relevant in this context (VBScript)?

Comment: 1) Are you getting the same error (_There is no file extension in 'C:\Users\My '._) when you try the second and third variants in your question? (2) Can you open the file by hand?

Comment: @ZevSpitz Like I said: I suspect that the error actually comes from a macro in `file.xlsm` (it's definitely not a VBScript error message). That's why I added the VBA tag. I could have added the Excel tag as well, but didn't feel the need. If you disagree: just edit the tags.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Not disagreeing; asking a theoretical question.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. I don't suspect it to be the excel file because I am able to open the excel file manually, but i will see if there is an issue with it. Also, when i use this same vb script on a different computer with a folder name that does not contain a space, it works fine and is able to open the excel file without any issues. The only time it doesn't work is when there is a space in a folder for the file path.

Comment: So, based on your update, what happens when you run this vbscript file manually. Do you have the same issue, or is it only when this vbscript is run through taskscheduler?

Comment: Yes it works now. It was task scheduler. I guess it uses a space character as a delimiter. I fixed the issue by simply putting the file path in quotes. Thank you all for your help